# Ubbi Dubbi c# program code

Tags: c#

Ubbi Dubbi is a program where before the first vowel in a word, the letters “ub” are inserted. On my code, it doesn't do it before the first vowel it does the second vowel. If I put "hello" the output is "hellubo", when it should be "hubello". Sorry if my english is bad, i'm still learning.

```
Console.Write("Enter word: ");
        string word = Console.ReadLine();
        var loc = word.IndexOfAny(new char[] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'});
        int aloc = word.IndexOf('a');
        int eloc = word.IndexOf('e');
        int iloc = word.IndexOf('i');
        int oloc = word.IndexOf('o');
        int uloc = word.IndexOf('u');
        if (aloc!= -1 && aloc > loc)
        {
            loc = aloc;
        }
         if (eloc!= -1 && eloc > loc)
       {
        loc = eloc;
       }
    if (iloc!= -1 && iloc > loc)
       {
           loc = iloc;
       }
    if (oloc!= -1 && oloc > loc)
       {
           loc = oloc;
       }
    if (uloc!= -1 && uloc > loc)
       {
        loc = uloc;
       }
     string word1 = word.Insert(loc, "ub");
    Console.WriteLine(word1);
```

Comment: According to wikipedia, "hello" should become "hubellubo": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubbi_dubbi... Are you speaking a different Ubbi Dubbi dialect? :)

Comment: @PaoloTedesco different

Answer (score 3):

After calling of `IndexOfAny` all work is done. So you can skip most of your code. But you should insert a check, if there is any vowel at all:

```
Console.Write("Enter word: ");
string word = Console.ReadLine();
var loc = word.IndexOfAny(new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' });

string word1 = loc >= 0 ? word.Insert(loc, "ub") : word;
Console.WriteLine(word1);
```

In your code an 'e' is found, so `loc = eloc` is executed. But there also 'o' is found and `loc = oloc` is executed AFTER the 'e'-check. So the final value of `loc` is that one of `oloc`.

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm reading this right, can you explain this part better?

Comment: First you check `eloc != -1`. This is true as eloc is 1 ('e' on position 1 in 'Hello') and so `loc = eloc`. After that you do the check for `oloc`. `oloc` is 4 which is not -1 and bigger than 1 (`oloc > loc`), so in the end `loc = 4`. If you would check for `oloc < loc` you would get the right result.

Comment: But as I told in my post, after the IndexOfAny line all other checks are not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it easily by below API.

```
private static string processWord(string word)
    {
        // Vowels array
        char[] vowels = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

        //Find the index of your first vowel in your 'word'
        int index = word.IndexOfAny(vowels);

        //Insert 'ub' at above location
        word = word.Insert(index, "ub");

        //Return the word
        return word;
    }
```

or

```
private static string processWord(string word)
    {
      return word.Insert(word.IndexOfAny(new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' }), "ub");
    }
```

Chose any method whichever easy for you to understand